# CoreData context not updating and bool always false?

Tags: core-data, swift4

I am trying to update a user record with a boolean value in coredata. The record itself is updating, but I can only see the change between app sessions, not the same session.

Essentially, I am trying to trap the user agreeing or refusing the apps terms of use. A check is performed on the landing screen after login and if the terms have been agreed to, then continue as normal. However, if the terms have not been agreed to then I need to fire a popover allowing them to accept the terms (This happens every time they hit the landing page until they accept)

1. I am running the check but no matter what the value is in the core data record, it always evaluates as false:

   ```
       let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
   context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")

   fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", userEmail)
   fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


   do {

       userRecord = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())

       if userRecord[0].acceptedTerms != nil && userRecord[0].acceptedTerms {
           print("Terms accepted, move along")
       } else {
           print("Terms refused, pop dialog")
       }

   } catch {
       print("No user found")
   }
   ```
2. When a user accepts the terms, I try to update the core data record. Which does update, however I can only see the update between app sessions. Whilst in the same session, if the user hits the landing screen again, the value is still set to false (Or at least the acceptedTerms field in core data is still a 0) - I have done some searching on this and seen there is     `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` and also `refreshAllObjects()` however neither seem to have any effect.

** Update with save code from AppDelegate **

```
func updateTermsComplete(userLogin: String, termsPermission: String){
    let context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", userLogin)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        userRecord = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [User]
    } catch {
        print("No user found")
    }
    if !userRecord.isEmpty {
        print("User already exists")
        userRecord[0].setValue(termsPermission, forKey: "acceptedTerms")
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("User updated")
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } catch {   
        }
        self.saveContext()
    }
    context.refreshAllObjects()
}

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling save() on your context  after performing the update?

Comment: Yes. I have tried explicitly calling context.save() after the function had executed and also tried a separate function (I have several different updates that run at different times) - neither works within the current app session.

Comment: Maybe you should include your update code as well.

Comment: Updated. We may look at shifting this to the cloud database instead due to time. However, it would be good to resolve this both to give us options for this app as well as future reference for other apps. Thanks